# Nodejs 4.1.1 does not run via daemontools - continuously get EPIPE errors

Tags: node.js

I'm running node.js on FreeBSD box, in a jail.  I made an upgrade of Node.js from 0.12.7 to 4.1.1 and my configuration for daemontools stopped working - I get EPIPE errors and it keeps restarting and overwhelms the machine.
If I execute the same script in an terminal it runs fine.

Can somebody please help me with this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you share your configuration?

Comment: I'm running node on a freebsd box 10.2 in a jail. Which configuration are you interested in ?

Comment: "and my congiguration for daemontools stopped working" <- this one.

Comment: I tried to use epipebomb module from npmjs but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Try re installing it. I faced same problem, and I fixed it by reinstalling it.

Comment: I reinstalled it couple of times with no effect - which component you propose to reinstall ?

Answer (score 0):

To make it work I switched from daemontools to runit - now it works like a charm